# SqlDependency in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, sqldependency

I'm new to Xamarin Forms, i use SqlDependency in Wpf which works fine. Now i want to use SqlDependency in xamarin Forms which showing me the following error.

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'MegaMartMobile.UnitEntrySN:_newMessage' (2) due to: Could not resolve type with token 0100004f from typeref (expected class 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlNotificationEventArgs' in assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') assembly:System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a type:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlNotificationEventArgs member:(null)

Bellow is my Sql Notifier code

```
public class UnitEntrySN
{
    public SqlCommand CurrentCommand { get; set; }
    private SqlConnection mConnection;
    public SqlConnection CurrentConnection
    {
        get
        {
            mConnection = mConnection ?? new SqlConnection(SqlCustomConnection.ConnectionString);
            return mConnection;
        }
    }
    public UnitEntrySN()
    {


        SqlDependency.Start(SqlCustomConnection.ConnectionString);
    }
    private event EventHandler<SqlNotificationEventArgs> _newMessage;

    public event EventHandler<SqlNotificationEventArgs> NewMessage
    {
        add
        {
            _newMessage += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            _newMessage -= value;
        }
    }

    public virtual void OnNewMessage(SqlNotificationEventArgs notification)
    {
        _newMessage?.Invoke(this, notification);
    }
    public DataTable RegisterDependency()
    {

        CurrentCommand = new SqlCommand("Select [UnitEntry_ID], [UnitEntry_Title], [UnitEntry_Description] from dbo.UnitEntrys where [UnitEntry_ID] != '1'", CurrentConnection)
        {
            Notification = null
        };


        var dependency = new SqlDependency(CurrentCommand);
        dependency.OnChange += Dependency_OnChange;


        if (CurrentConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            CurrentConnection.Open();
        try
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(CurrentCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        return null;
    }
    private void Dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        var dependency = sender as SqlDependency;
        dependency.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(Dependency_OnChange);
        OnNewMessage(e);



    }



    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(SqlCustomConnection.ConnectionString);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and code in view model

```
public UnitEntrySN Notifier { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<UnitEntryModel> mUnitEntrySource;
    public ObservableCollection<UnitEntryModel> UnitEntrySource
    {
        get
        {
            mUnitEntrySource = mUnitEntrySource ?? new ObservableCollection<UnitEntryModel>();
            return mUnitEntrySource;
        }
    }
    private void Notifier_NewMessageAsync(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {

        this.LoadMessage(Notifier.RegisterDependency());


    }
    private void LoadMessage(DataTable dt)
    {
        if (dt != null)
        {
            UnitEntrySource.Clear();

            foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
            {
                var msg = new UnitEntryModel
                {

                    UnitEntry_Title = Convert.ToString(drow["UnitEntry_Title"])

                };
                UnitEntrySource.Add(msg);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a remote database?

Comment: yes, i want to connect to a remote database

Comment: Well to be very honest I would not do that I would rather have a web service contact the database, a [php](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html) or [asp.net](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/web-api-tutorials) Web-API should do the trick

Comment: @UsmanAli did you find solution? i have the same problem. i am using .net standard 2.0 with xamarin forms

Comment: What version of .NET Core? Make sure all of the libraries and their dependencies are able to work with the version of .NET Core you are compiling with.